# Django quill editor | field name displays inside quill editor widget border in Django admin

Tags: django

I am new to Django + Python. I can't really figure out why my field name get displayed inside the Quill Widget in Django admin. It would be great if someone who already figured out this problem share their solution.

Django==3.2.4 | django-quill-editor==0.1.22

My code:

```
# models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    post = QuillField("Post", null=True, blank=True)


# admin.py
@admin.register(Title)
class TitleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo29O.png) - Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to embed an image.

Many thanks,